# Adobe Livecycle binding query

Tags: binding, livecycle

Hi I am using Adobes Lifecycle and want to bind 2 fields together, but want the second field to be slightly different to the first based on a rule. The best way to explain this is page numbering:

If I had 2 pages in my form, I name the first field on page 1 "1" bind this to a field on the second page which I want to automatically show as "2". So my requirement is to be able to take the data in page 1 and increase it by 1 and display this on page 2, I could then do the same for a third page and so on.

This isnt actually my requirement but very similar.

Any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Settle for binding the element on page 1. On that field's change-event, do something like this:

```
xfa.resolveNode("xfa.form..page2.." + this.name).rawValue = this.rawValue + 1;
```

Oh, and make sure you name the field on page 2 the same as on page 1.